# I want to reference a whitepaper which has no author but is from a corporation

Tags: bibtex

I want to reference the following white paper:

```
@ONLINE{TegraX1,
    author = {NVIDIA Corporation},
    title = {NVIDIA Tegra X1 NVIDIA'S New Mobile Supechip},
    month = Jan.,   
    year = {2015},
    url = {http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/tegra_white_papers/tegra-K1-whitepaper.pdf}
}
```

However this paper does not have any information about a certain author, it is more like the company behinds it. Thus, I do not know how to give the author properly, or if this is even the correct format. Furthermore, this iwll only show "Corperation" in the pdf where sourced, where it would be nicer to have a more valuable short like Nvidia Coop or sth like this.

Comment: What about `author = {{NVIDIA Corporation}},`? Note that if you use `biblatex`, you will have more options regarding how to do names (e.g., there is a `shortauthor` field you can use). But note that for traditional BibTeX, how things appear depend on the `.bst` you use, and you have not given that information.

Comment: Wow thank you - I am fairly new to LateX and just use it once or twice a year, but this does the trick